# C# - ClickOnce web deployment issue, shows XML code instead of launching

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

I have just uploaded my published application files to my web server but I am having problems deploying them.  When I open the "publish.htm" and click the "Launch" button, it opens the .application file and shows the XML code.  Even manually entering the URL for the .application has the same result.  I am currently using Firefox 3.5 but I have successfully installed other peoples' applications this same way recently using Firefox.  It also fails in Internet Explorer 8 as well.  Not sure if if file permissions would have an effect on this, but if so, what should they be set to?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice short one on using Click Once (and other techs) with an Apache. http://software.clempaul.me.uk/articles/clickonce/

t sami

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that your web server is not correctly delivering the MIME type for the ClickOnce files. According to Microsoft documentation, the following MIME types must be configured.

```
.application: application/x-ms-application
.manifest:    application/x-ms-manifest
.deploy:      application/octet-stream
```

If you do that, everything should work fine.

**EDIT**
Please note that this is a configuration issue on the server side - it has nothing to do with the browser you're using. It does not matter if your ClickOnce files are hosted by IIS, Apache or any other web server, as long as it recognizes and sends the MIME types correctly.

You may also google for "ClickOnce MIME [Name of Web Server]".

Comment: So? Add the respective lines to a .htaccess document you place in the ClickOnce folder. In case you're not on an Apache host or you're not allowed to add your own .htaccess files, you'll have to contact your hosting company.

Comment: Also: there's no other way around that. Either you make the web server use the correct MIME types or you can't use ClickOnce.